# Javascript works locally but not on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm a bit new to web programming, and I'm trying to include a jQuery widget (pop-up calender when you click on the textbox) on my website. When I open the html script in chrome locally the widget works fine, but on my website it doesn't work at all.

When I visit my website as a regular user, Chrome says "Not Secure" before the https://________  . Maybe this has something to do with it?

Sorry for the big block of code but I don't know where the mistake in my script is.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="appointment">
  </head>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/master/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>



<body>
  <h2 class="content-head is-center">SET UP AN APPOINTMENT <em>(Optional)</em></h2>
  <aside>
       <p> We can meet you on campus or at our office!
    <br>
    <br>
    Please use the form below to schedule an appointment. 
                  </p>
   </aside>

<!-- START FORM -->

  <form id="gform" method="POST" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked"
  action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyFvR4QUsL6wSpQbv283kcZuyKDM_vTGbSeqvM91UykoFah9s4/exec">

    <fieldset class="pure-group">
      <label for="name">Name* : </label>
<p>
      <input id="name" firstNname="firstName" placeholder="First Name" /> </p>
<br>
    <p><input id="name" lastNname="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" /></p>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="pure-group">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyFvR4QUsL6wSpQbv283kcZuyKDM_vTGbSeqvM91UykoFah9s4/exec" >


  </form>

  <!-- POST SUBMISSION -->
  <div style="display:none;" id="thankyou_message">
    <h2>Thank you for getting in touch with us.
      We look forward to meeting with you!</h2>
  </div>

  <!-- Submit the Form to Google Using "AJAX" -->
  <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/master/form-submission-handler.js"></script>
  <!-- <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"
  src="/form-submission-handler.js"></script> -->

<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"
src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/master/form-submission-handler.js"></script>
<!-- END -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using http:// instead of https://?

Comment: "it doesn't work" - how can we help if we don't know what the problem is?

Comment: Try by removing http: and https: from all stylesheets and js links

Comment: `http://yui.yahooapis.com...` is not a secure origin so the stylesheet would compromise your security anyway.

Comment: Why are you using https/http links and some that are just //? Use either style, the // links usually won't work on a purely local file (from my experience). Press F12 to open the Console and have a look what errors you're actually seeing while loading that site. Oh and your last inclusion is the same as the one before it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working, because you placed JS/jquery multiple times. This version should work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="appointment">
  </head>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/master/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>



<body>
  <h2 class="content-head is-center">SET UP AN APPOINTMENT <em>(Optional)</em></h2>
  <aside>
       <p> We can meet you on campus or at our office!
    <br>
    <br>
    Please use the form below to schedule an appointment. 
                  </p>
   </aside>

<!-- START FORM -->

  <form id="gform" method="POST" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked"
  action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyFvR4QUsL6wSpQbv283kcZuyKDM_vTGbSeqvM91UykoFah9s4/exec">

    <fieldset class="pure-group">
      <label for="name">Name* : </label>
<p>
      <input id="name" firstNname="firstName" placeholder="First Name" /> </p>
<br>
    <p><input id="name" lastNname="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" /></p>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="pure-group">

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyFvR4QUsL6wSpQbv283kcZuyKDM_vTGbSeqvM91UykoFah9s4/exec" >


  </form>

  <!-- POST SUBMISSION -->
  <div style="display:none;" id="thankyou_message">
    <h2>Thank you for getting in touch with us.
      We look forward to meeting with you!</h2>
  </div>

  <!-- Submit the Form to Google Using "AJAX" -->
  <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/master/form-submission-handler.js"></script>
  <!-- <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"
  src="/form-submission-handler.js"></script> -->
<!-- END -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some resources with **http://** url are included in your source code, So that is why it's showing **"Not Secure"**. 
I would suggest to include all your Javascript libraries related to your functionality at the bottom of your html.